# Writing with Server in C++

Tags: java, c++, sockets, server

I am programming a server-client service, the client is in Java and the Server is in C++, but when I try to write by the Server to the Client, he does not sends the message, only when i close the socket, the server sends the message and the client reads it. Here is the Server Code:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<sstream>
#include<string>
#include<netdb.h>
#include<netinet/in.h>
#include<string.h>
#include<iostream>
#include<sys/types.h>
#include<sys/socket.h>
#include<arpa/inet.h>
#include<unistd.h>


using namespace std;

void doprocessing (int sock, int cliente);
void sendM(int socket,int client);

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
   int sockfd, newsockfd, portno,cliente;
   char buffer[256];
   struct sockaddr_in serv_addr, cli_addr;
   int n, pid;
   socklen_t clilen;


   sockfd = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);

   if (sockfd < 0) {
      perror("ERROR opening socket");
      exit(1);
   }

   bzero((char *) &serv_addr, sizeof(serv_addr));
   portno = 8080;

   serv_addr.sin_family = AF_INET;
   serv_addr.sin_addr.s_addr = INADDR_ANY;
   serv_addr.sin_port = htons(portno);

   if (bind(sockfd, (struct sockaddr *) &serv_addr, sizeof(serv_addr)) < 0) {
      perror("ERROR on binding");
      exit(1);
   }


   listen(sockfd,5);
   clilen = sizeof(cli_addr);
   cout<<"Servidor Iniciado1..."<<endl;

   while (1) {
      newsockfd = accept(sockfd, (struct sockaddr *) &cli_addr, &clilen);
      cliente=cliente+1;
      if (newsockfd < 0) {
         perror("ERROR aceptando conexion");
         exit(1);
      }
      /* Create child process */
           pid = fork();

           if (pid < 0) {
              perror("ERROR on fork");
              exit(1);
           }

           if (pid == 0) {

             cout<<"Nueva conexion "<<cliente<<endl;
              close(sockfd);
              doprocessing(newsockfd,cliente);
              exit(0);
           }
           else {
              close(newsockfd);
           }

   }
}

void doprocessing (int sock, int cliente1) {
   int n;
   char buffer1[256];
   bzero(buffer1,256);
   n = read(sock,buffer1,255);
   n=1;
   if (n < 0) {
      perror("ERROR leyendo el socket");
      exit(1);
   }
   cout<<"Mensaje de cliente "<<cliente1<<":"<<buffer1<<endl;
   sendM(sock,cliente1);
   if (n < 0) {
      perror("ERROR escribiendo al socket");
      exit(1);
   }

}

void sendM(int socket, int client){
    std :: string buff;
    int n;
    cout << "\nServidor: ";
    cin >> buff;
    n=send(socket, buff.data(), buff.length(),0);
    cout<<buff.data()<<"\n";
    cout<<n<<endl;
    if(n<0){
            cout<<"Error enviando respuesta"<<endl;
        }
    doprocessing(socket,client);
}
```

This is the Cliente code in Java

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.net.Socket;

public class Conexion {

    BufferedReader lector = null;
    PrintWriter escritor = null;
    public Socket sockete;
    Thread principal=null;
    String mensaje_in=null;

    public Conexion(){
        Conectar();
    }
    public void Conectar(){
        principal = new Thread(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                try {
                        if(sockete==null){
                        sockete = new Socket("192.168.0.103", 8080);
                        Leer();}

                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });
        principal.start();

    }
    public void Leer(){
        Thread leer_hilo=new Thread(new Runnable(){
            public void run(){

                try{
                    lector=new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(sockete.getInputStream()));
                    while(true){
                        String mensaje= lector.readLine();
                        //System.out.println(lector.readLine());
                        if (lector==null){
                            System.out.println("NO se conecta");
                        }
                        else{
                             System.out.println("Este es el mensaje: "+mensaje);
                             break;
                        }
                    }

                  }catch(Exception ex){
                    ex.printStackTrace();

                  }
            }

        });
        leer_hilo.start();

    }

    /**
     * Envia datos al servidor
     * @param dato
     */
    public void Escribir(String dato){

        try{
            escritor= new PrintWriter(sockete.getOutputStream(), true);
            escritor.println(dato);
            System.out.println(dato);
        }catch(Exception ex){
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }

    }


}
```

Comment: How is this a Java question?

Comment: Perhaps you could cut and paste the exact text from your terminal - showing your typing as well as the `cout` messages....?

Comment: Testing your server with telnet as a client works ok, the server reads and sends the responses properly. So your problem is probably in the Java client code, please add that to the question also.

Comment: I tried the java client to a server made ​​in java and read correctly only when the server in C ++ does not read the msg , only when I close the socket from the server.

I added the client code in Java Up

Comment: Check the socket properties. After the `send` call the content is not necessary sent immediatly. You can also avoid developping directly with raw sockets : a lot of frameworks exist to do message passing over network, for example, check zeromq or grpc ...